# hide concurrent request in srs window oracle apps

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I have written a fnd_request.submit_request function in after report trigger.
The request is getting submitted and is getting displayed as new concurrent request in SRS window.

For some reason I need to hide this new request from SRS screen.

I have tried disabling "use in srs" checkbox but it seems to be working only for concurrent program without parameters.

Please help

Comment: _For some reason I need to hide this..._ And it will not work at all if you remove the request from the request group?

Comment: This request contains login credentials .. and for security concerns we have to hide the request from srs window